# Generic Issue, any Suggestions?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

// UITableView+.Swift Extension

```
extension UITableView {

 func cellForModel<T: CellViewModel>(at: IndexPath, model: T) -> T.CellType  {
    let cell: T.CellType = dequeueReusableCell()
    *let t = model as! T.CellType.ModelType*
    cell.setupModel(model: t)
    return cell
  }

  func dequeueReusableCell<T: ReusableCell>() -> T {
    print(T.reuseIdentifier())
    let temp = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier())

    return temp as! T
  }
}
```

// CellViewModel.Swift

```
protocol CellViewModel where Self: NSObject, CellType: ReusableCell {
  associatedtype CellType
}
```

// ReusableCell.Swift

```
protocol ReusableCell where Self: UITableViewCell, ModelType: CellViewModel {
  associatedtype ModelType
  static func reuseIdentifier() -> String
  func setupModel(model: ModelType)
  var cell: UITableViewCell { get }
}

extension ReusableCell {
  static func reuseIdentifier() -> String {
    return String(describing: Self.self)
  }
  var cell: UITableViewCell {
    return self as UITableViewCell
  }
}
```

**My question is, why I need to do `let t = model as! T.CellType.ModelType` this in UITableView Extension instead of just passing the model to `setupModel(model: ModelType)` function.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the constraint `CellType.ModelType == Self` to `CellViewModel`

```
protocol CellViewModel where Self: NSObject, CellType: ReusableCell, CellType.ModelType == Self {
    associatedtype CellType
}
```